# Django + Strophe + ejabberd - troubles with attach and groupchat

Tags: django, ejabberd, strophe

I try to use strophe + ejabberd to make something like webchat.

What i've done already:

- when I login to website, i also authenticate to ejabberd (to achieve RID and SID),
- after login is finished, i attach RID and SID i got from context processor,
- connection status seems to be: connection established, logs:

.

```
POST: <body rid='406266360' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='9c66aa19123e96dc2925c24d4f985d458763eb67'><presence xmlns='jabber:client'><priority>-1</priority></presence><presence to='localhost/m' xmlns='jabber:client'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/></presence></body>

RESP: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'><success xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'/></body>
```

After that, connection hangs on:

```
POST: <body rid='406266361' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='9c66aa19123e96dc2925c24d4f985d458763eb67'/>
```

When i try to send a message now (while its hanged):

```
POST: <body rid='406266362' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' sid='175e45333109f74c36f9dffbe4e3cc6cffc80df4'><message to='localhost' type='groupchat' xmlns='jabber:client'><body>yrdy</body></message></body>
```

Im getting:

```
RESP: <body type='terminate' condition='remote-stream-error' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'><stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/></stream:error></body>
```

Whats wrong? Strange thing is that after some seconds request is aborted, and next request hangs again. When i try to send message then, there are no errors but response is:

```
RESP: <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
```

With no errors (connection is still connected and authenticated, but message doesnt seem to be delivered).

Code I use to send message:

```
var body = $('#input_text').val();                                                            |        // make sure this presence is for the right room
var msg_body = {                                                                              |        if (room === Groupie.room) {
    to: Chat.room,                                                                       |            var nick = Strophe.getResourceFromJid(from);
    type: 'groupchat'                                                                         |
}                                                                                             |            if ($(presence).attr('type') === 'error' &&
var msg = $msg(msg_body).c('body').t(body);                                                   |                !Groupie.joined) {
                                                                                              |                // error joining room; reset app
Chat.connection.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Strophe.js to attach like so:

```
Chat.connection = new Strophe.Connection(Chat.BOSH_SERVICE_URL);
Chat.connection.attach(jid, sid, rid, onConnectHandler);
```

*onConnectHandler* is then called once you've attached successfully. From then one, you don't have to worry about the SID and RID again (until page reload).

Also, are you aware of the [MUC strophe plugin](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/muc)?

If you want some example code to use/study, I wrote something similar to what you're doing for [Plone](http://plone.org), called [collective.xmpp.chat](https://github.com/collective/collective.xmpp.chat)

The javascript is reusable separately: [converse.js](http://conversejs.org)

Comment: Its done by Strophe. I've done exactly that what you suggested at the beginning, after that everything is handled by Strophe (i mean RID increasing). But RID is correct I think. I ran my ejabberd in debug mode and i see that server is getting message correctly (after that first hang abort, not before). Nevertheless, my handler for public message is not casted (nor any else). So current diagnose is: Strophe is sending message (with that small issue with hanging connection), message is not received by Strophe.

Thank you for links. I will take a look.

Comment: AH i see what u meant. Its just a copy, thats why RID is different.